# How many revisions are too much for a submitted manuscripts?

Tags: journals, paper-submission, journal-workflow

I have submitted a manuscript to a journal. The journal can let me revise the manuscript. In total, I have revise it 5-6 times. I am wondering, will too much revision hurt my chance of being accepted? Can the editor reject my manuscript due to this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A journal that allows revisions during the review process is a new phenomenon for me. Assume that an editor has assigned me as a reviewer. Every time that you revise then, I would get a notice that you have revised your manuscript. This means, that all my previous review work needs to be rechecked against your newest revision. Or, I will not get a notice or I ignore the notice and your latest revisions will not be read by me. I will not be happy with this situation. I would have hoped that you would have revised your manuscript thoroughly before you submitted it.

An editor could come to the conclusion that you are not helpful with the editing process. A good one might ask you to make one final revision before your manuscript goes into the review process. Another editor might indeed decide that you are abusing the revision-while-in-process process and desk-reject your paper.

I would advise you to offer to withdraw the paper until you are ready to submit a version that is final on your side.

If your journal is predatory, the review process is going to be so tainted that it does not matter. Hopefully, you selected better.